# Azure Data Factory - Copy Data - add values to output

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a 'Copy Data' activity withing Azure Data Factory that calls out to a REST endpoint and stores the data in a JSON file.

Within the JSON data that is retrieved there is some data about the total number of records and remaining records that I would like to add to the output of the 'Copy Data' activity.

How would I extract this information and add it to the output, so the next activity in the flow could make use of it?

Comment: @activity(“Activity Name”).output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of any activity at a given time is;

```
@activity(“Activity Name”).output
```

so for example you could get the total number of rows copied like this;

```
@activity("Activity Name").output.rowsCopied
```

you should be able to access everything from the output object;

- dataRead
- dataWritten
- rowsRead
- rowsCopied
- copyDuration

etc..

Comment: Can I add my own custom 'properties' onto the output object?
So for example I can later consume the value of @activity("Activity Name").output.myCustomProperty

Comment: you can use the lookup activity to obtain values from previous activities (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) - you could use variables to store values if they are